# JSESSIONID Issue When Tomcat Server is Acting As a Proxy for Another Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat, servlets, session-state

I have a (1) Tomcat Server app.  It is proxying calls to a second (2) App Server  (3rd party), as in:

End-user --> My (1) Tomcat Server app --> second (2) App Server

When the end-user authenticates with my (1) Tomcat Server app, my (1) Tomcat Server app, in turns logs into the second (2) App Server on the end-users behalf.

The second (2) App Server then generates a JESSIONID. I need that JESSIONID to be the one that is associated with the end-user who is interacting with my (1) Tomcat server app.

The issue seems to be that the second (2) App Server is maintaing a single session with My (1) Tomcat Server, so that if multiple end-users are interacting with My (1) Tomcat server, they all end up sharing a single session.

(I hope that made sense)

What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Thanks much in advance for any help!

Comment: If you use HttpClient from Tomcat 1 -> Tomcat 2 and you have a global connection, it's probably managing cookies globally. You're going to want to change those connections to be per-user instead of globally-shared.

Answer (score 0):

How do you invoke app2 from app1 ? Using the http client library or something similar?

> The issue seems to be that the second (2) App Server is maintaing a single session with My (1) Tomcat Server, so that if multiple end-users are interacting with My (1) Tomcat server, they all end up sharing a single session.

I can see 2 options

1. You can store the JSESSIONID of the second app in the session of the first app. Every time you proxy the second app from the first, look up the JSESSIONID of the 2nd app from the user session on the first and include that in your request
2. The first time you receive the JSESSIONID from app2, send the cookie back in the response to the user. Every subsequent call will automatically have the JSESSIONID flowing into app1 which will be proxied to app2. But to achieve this, you will have to change the session cookie name for app1 to something else.

Comment: I invoke app2 with CloseableHttpClient httpclient.execute().

Comment: Also, I'm not using sessions at all in (1) my app.

Comment: I had previously tried something similar to your first suggestion, but my (1) Tomcat Server app insists on sending a single stored JESSIONID that I can't remove.  If I add JSESSIONID that I get from having cookied the end-user then add that to my request to (2) App Server, it doesn't work because the original JSESSIONID that my (1) Tomcat Server app sends is _also_ sent.

Comment: Just change the name of the session cookie of the first app? @Ralph's answer below shows how it can be done. Combine that with the suggestions I posted.